# How do I reload a specific object (Table) in a DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I'm using the same Data Context for my entire WPF application. How can I reload a specific object from the database? I tried the Refresh function of the data context for that object to no success.

Comment: What actually you want from refresh, to remap the entities?

Comment: I want to reload an entity. Say I loaded an entity of Student with ID 5. The user made changes to the properties of that entity but decided to cancel. I want to be able to reload that Student entity back from the database to revert any changes made.

Answer (score 0):

You do;

YourDataContext = null;
YourDataContext = Database.Read();

Comment: But isn't this the equivlant of re-declaring the data context?

In Linq 2 Sql, once a row is read, it's kept in memory. I want to be able to re-read a row (entity) from the database without wiping the rest of the cached entities in the Data Context.